# How can i send data into blockchain

Tags: blockchain, nodejs

please i dont come to send data from form with inputs to blockchain database, using nodejs, web3 and dust (engine templating ) ?

please share some exemples if exists ..

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

you could include the message in a simple transaction using :

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({from: source, to: destination, data: "your message"});
```

or create a contract and call a storage function with your inputs e.g

```
yContractInstance.myMethod("your message",[, param2, ...] [, transactionObject] [, defaultBlock] [, callback]);
```

please read the official [documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-methods)